# Disallowing direct access to video

Tags: asp.net, flowplayer

I use FlowPlayer to play my videos on my website, however I don't want people to directly download my video for example by typing www.mysite.com/video.mp4.

Does anyone know how to create rule in IIS to stop this from happening? Maybe redirect to the main page?

Comment: You don't have a very nice accept-rate. Accept more answers to improve this, and you might have more people delivering an answer. Everybody wants to be rewarded.

Comment: you try to avoid the download in general, or they take the link and place it in other sites ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FlowPlayer runs client-side. In other words, it is loaded on the webbrowser once the page's HTML has been transferred from the server to the client.

This means that the file must be downloaded from the outside anyway through the browser itself (since FlowPlayer is just pointing to that file, letting the browser know where to fetch it from). Therefore, there is no way of concealing the file entirely.

However, you could make it harder to find. However, I don't think that's ever possible with FlowPlayer. You'd had to program your own techniques which would allow direct streaming of server-side content.

Comment: I see, how about only letting my site stream it? Is that possible? To prevent them from streaming directly from my site.

Comment: I know you can't hide the file, but maybe I can only allow requests from my server to go in. I did the same for images using URL Rewrite, so only my server can access them.

Answer (score 1):

you could, but might be quite hard:
The solution I would see is to serve the video thought an httpHandler.
I would then use sessionID to choose if the video should be served or not. If SessionID match with the caller request you serve  the video to the client, otherwise no.